# How to pop to the parent window in a tab?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to replace the default Back button to a custom image button in a Titanium iOS project.

I am opening several windows in a tab with the following code:

```
currentTab.open(childWindow);
```

How do I "pop" back to the previous (parent) window?

I tried the following:

```
childWindow.close();
```

and:

```
currentTab.close(childWindow);
```

But both don't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew's answer helped and I solved the problem with `win.close()` function call.

The reason it was giving the following error:

> Undefined is not a variable.

was because I was trying to access the window variable with a wrong reference.

```
this.backButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
 this.win.close();
});
```

`this.win` was the variable for the child window, and stupidly I used the same inside the backButton event listener, where `this` was recognized as the callback function and it gave me the above error.

Just changing it to the following helped.

```
_this = this;
this.backButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
 _this.win.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

They added a method named `popToRootWindow` in Ti SDK 6.2

Reference : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Tab-method-popToRootWindow

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is wrong on your side without checking the actual code. However here is the snippet of code which does exactly what you are looking for. It allows to open two windows in one tab. The onclick listener on the second window simple closes this window. It in turn triggers the first window to come up. Maybe it can be helpful to spot a problem in your code.

Here is the contents of `index.js`:

```
$.index.open();

var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({title: 'Window 1'});
win1.add(Titanium.UI.createLabel({text: 'Window 1'}));
var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({bottom: 0, title: 'Next'});
win1.add(button1);

button1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({title: 'Window 2'});
    win2.add(Titanium.UI.createLabel({text: 'Window 2'}));
    var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({bottom: 0, title: 'Back to Window 1'});
    win2.add(button2);

    button2.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        win2.close();
    });

    tab.open(win2);
});

var tab = Titanium.UI.createTab({title: 'Tab 1', window: win1});
tabGroup.addTab(tab);
tabGroup.open();
```

Note: `index.xml` file for this example can be very simple: with only one empty element `Window class="container"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it.